# Finding all eigen-values and corresponding eigen-vectors of a matrix over $(i)$ the real field $R$ and $(ii)$ the complex field $C$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\   2 &-1  \end{bmatrix} $. Find all eigen-values and corresponding eigen-vectors of $B$ viewed as a matrix over $(i)$ the real field $R$ and $(ii)$ the complex field $C$.

I am ok with 2nd part i.e. for complex field. Little confused in real field. what will be egienvalues and eigenvectors in R?

Comment: The matrix has no real eigenvalues.

Comment: @D.Deepak Having eigenvalues is equivalent to having eigenvectors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Characteristic equation of $B$ is:
$ ( \lambda )^2 +1 = 0$. i.e. $ \lambda = \pm i $

$(i) $ No eigen-value and eigen-vector is there for $ \mathbb{R} $ .

$ (ii) $ For $ \mathbb{C} $ , eigen-values are $ \pm i $ ,
further you can proceed for eigen-vectors by usual method.